# How to Ignore Bracketing Style in Code Comparison / Diff

Tags: difference, diff

How to ignore bracketing styles when doing code comparisons or diffs? We have several formats of bracketing and I would like:

```
function foo(){
}
```

to be considered the same as

```
function foo()
{
}
```

Right now I use Araxis merge which does a direct line-by-line comparison and we are getting a lot of "false positive" changes.

Comment: Run your code through a formatter before diffing it, that way you can use existing high quality diff tools.

Comment: some diff tools let you ignore whitespace entirely

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487

Comment: Note to reviewers: the suggested edit was made in collaboration with the OP.

Comment: @ypercube clarifications like "edit was made in collaboration with the OP" would better be placed into [edit summary](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/57720) so that reviewers could see these (comments are not displayed to them)

Comment: @gnat thnx, and noted. I had added a long edit summary but forgot to clarify this.

Comment: You've got 3 options on how you want to take this.  If you want to ask about how to make Araxis merge handle this, SO may be a better target (specific tool use).  If you are asking about workflows and team style guides, then P.SE (though I suspect there's a dup for it that you should read first).  If you are looking for a new tool, then Software Recommendations.SE may be appropriate - given enough information about your features and environment.

Answer (score 1):

A tool like [Semantic Merge](http://www.semanticmerge.com/index.html) which understands the language semantics by parsing the code  will work in this case.

Comment: Could someone please explain the downvotes? I've never used Semantic Merge and at first glance it looks like a good suggestion.